# How to remove a word/string from div content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My div contains words 'abc def ghi fij' etc
like this `<div id='elements'>abc def ghi fij..</div>`
How can i remove a certain word from it and place the remaining word in same div
like removing "def ghi"
and make new content to div like
`<div id='elements'>abc fij..</div>` using javascript
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use function overload of [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text)

```
$('#elements').text(function(t){
    return t.replace("def ghi", "");
});
```